# How to combine two matrices column wise to strings separated by comma?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices

```
A = [   1  3
        4  3]  
B  = [  2  1 
        4  1 ]
```

I want to combine A and B to produce the string array

```
C = [  "1,2"   "3,1" 
       "4,1"  "3,1"  ]
```

How can I do this in MATLAB? I tried it this way

```
for i = 1: 4; 
    for j = 1: 4; 
        fprintf('%0.2f,%0.2f\n',A(i,j),B(i,j) ) 
    end 
end
```

Appreciate your suggestions !

Comment: `,` and space mean the same. Are you aware? If yes, what do you mean by "separated by comma"?

Comment: @Sardar Usama   I mean comma not space,  I want to combine each element of each column of matrix A with matrix B. It should produce something like C (e.g., 1,2 should be first element of matrix C). I tried it this way 
'  for i  = 1: 4;
      for j  = 1: 4;
      fprintf('%0.2f,%0.2f\n',A(i,j),B(i,j) )
     end
    end   '
But this one does not produce a matrix like C. It just combine each element of the matrices.

Comment: Can you please add an answer demonstrating your suggestions?

Comment: @SardarUsama, Infact I want to build a table from MATLAB that I can import to latex directly. The table format, for instance, is  like A +- B, thats why I want to add a comma so that  I can easily replace it with \pm in latex. I will update the question with code I posted in comments.

Comment: Please update your question with the above stated detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note, is that there is a difference between strings `"string"` and character arrays `'character array'`. Whereas strings are one entity, the character array is an array of characters.

Thus you can make the following assignment

```
A(1) = "Hello";
```

but not

```
B(1) = 'Hello';
```

because the `B(1)` is one value, and `'Hello'` is 5 values (H,e,l,l,o).

Secondly, you cannot use `fprintf` as you suggest in the comments as it only prints (as in its name) and the variable returned by `fprintf` is the number of characters printed. Instead, to construct the string use [`strcat`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) together with [`num2str`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html?searchHighlight=%60num2str%60&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), such that you get:

```
A = rand(2); %some matrices
B = rand(2);

for i = 1:2
    for j = 1:2
        C(i,j) = strcat(num2str(A(i,j)),",",num2str(B(i,j)));
    end
end
```

**EDIT:** If you are anyway going to interchange the comma for `\pm` in LaTeX, you can just do it when constructing `C` by using

```
C(i,j) = strcat(num2str(A(i,j)),"\pm",num2str(B(i,j)))
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
  A = [1 3; 4 3];
  B = [2 1; 4 1];
  C = A + "," + B

 C = 

   %  2×2 string array

    %  "1,2"    "3,1"
    %  "4,4"    "3,1"
```

Comment: This is just elegant as hell. How is this not the answer?